# Trying to tween Color3 values based on local time

Tags: lua, roblox

So I'm making a plugin on www.roblox.com and I've encountered a problem, despite how I successfully get their time, this code doesn't seem to properly adjust the script editor colors. I think my math may be off? (Note: I use a built-in function :lerp for Vector3 values and simply convert from Vector3 and Color3 as to avoid making my own custom lerp function.)

Code:

```
local S = settings().Studio
local toolbar = plugin:CreateToolbar("Time of day Script Editor")
local Toggle = toolbar:CreateButton("Enable", "Enable Time of day Script Editor", "")
local Options = {"Background Color", "Comment Color", "Error Color", "Keyword Color", "Number Color", "Operator Color", "Preprocessor Color", "Selection Background Color", "Selection Color", "String Color","Text Color", "Warning Color"}
local Original = {["Background Color"] = Color3.new(1, 1, 1), ["Comment Color"] = Color3.new(0, 127/255, 0), ["Error Color"] = Color3.new(1, 0, 0), ["Keyword Color"] = Color3.new(0, 0, 127/255), ["Number Color"] = Color3.new(0, 127/255, 127/255), ["Operator Color"] = Color3.new(127/255, 127/255, 0), ["Preprocessor Color"] = Color3.new(127/255, 0, 0), ["Selection Background Color"] = Color3.new(110/255, 161/255, 241/255), ["Selection Color"] = Color3.new(1, 1, 1), ["String Color"] = Color3.new(127/255, 0, 127/255),["Text Color"] = Color3.new(0, 0, 0), ["Warning Color"] = Color3.new(0, 0, 1)}
local Active = false

local Lighting = game.Lighting

local function C3V3(c3) --Convert a Color3 into Vector3
    return Vector3.new(c3.r, c3.g, c3.b)
end

local function V3C3(v3) --Convert a Vector3 into a Color3
    return Color3.new(v3.x, v3.y, v3.z)
end

local function Color3Lerp(start, fin, decimal) --Return a lerped Color3
    return V3C3(C3V3(start):lerp(C3V3(fin), decimal))
end

local function GetLocalTime() --Get their local time
    local t = tick()
    local hour = math.floor(t/60/60%24)
    local minute = math.floor(t/60%60)
    return hour .. ":" .. minute .. ":00"
end

local function GetMinutes(T) --Get minutes
    local Orig = Lighting.TimeOfDay --Original .TimeOfDay property
    local Minutes = nil
    Lighting.TimeOfDay = T --Set to time
    Minutes = Lighting:GetMinutesAfterMidnight() --Get minutes after midnight
    Lighting.TimeOfDay = Orig --Set back to original so user doesn't notice
    return Minutes
end

local function GetDecimal(minutes) --Get decimal used for lerping
    return minutes < 720 and  minutes/720 or (minutes-720)/720
end

local function DeterminePoints(start, fin, minutes) --Determine start and end values of the lerp based on the local time
    if minutes >= 720 then
        return start,fin
    else
        return fin,start
    end
end

local function Invert(Color) --Invert a color
    return Color3.new(1 - Color.r, 1 - Color.g, 1 - Color.b)
end

Toggle.Click:connect(function() --When the plugin is used
    Active = not Active
    Toggle:SetActive(Active)
    while Active do
        for i = 1,#Options do
            local Min = GetMinutes(GetLocalTime()) --Get minutes
            local start, fin = DeterminePoints(Original[Options[i]], Invert(Original[Options[i]]), Min) --Get start and finish points
            S[Options[i]] = Color3Lerp(start, fin, GetDecimal(Min)) --Lerp it
        end
        wait(60) --Wait a minute before repeating
    end
end)
```

It does change the colors, and it doesn't give errors, but it doesn't change to the proper colors.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Have you added debugging print/log statements to this code to see that it is correctly being run and correctly calculating the values you are trying to get? Assuming it does that correctly then the problem would seem to be in the code that activates/sets the colors.

Comment: Well, I know for sure the inverts work and I know my GetMinutes function works.. I know the loop/active stuff works. I'm pretty sure the problem arises when I'm either getting the start/end points or when I'm getting the decimal to use.

Comment: An unrelated question but how is `Active` supposed to change in the loop?

Comment: When the plugin button gets clicked it fires the event, in which the line Active = not Active does the job.

Comment: That's before the loop though. Once it toggles it hits a loop and then how can it change again?

Comment: When the button is clicked again the event fires again. It's a roblox thing but trust me, I've coded on that site for at least 3 years, that's how it works

Comment: That's how what works? Infinite loops ending on their own? `wait` killing a loop/event handler? But ok.

Comment: Well you see, when the event fires a function is run. It's kind of like multi threading I suppose. It's built in, one event doesn't need to end for another to fire. So when it fires again and Active is set to false the loop still going from the other event ends.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82335/discussion-between-warspyking-and-etan-reisner).

Comment: Somebody told me perhaps HSL tweening was the way to go, they gave me an HSL->RGB converter, how would I tween HSL though?